# Swift mutating func in Singleton

Tags: ios, swift

In `Swift` I have this Singleton

```
struct Networking {
    static let shared = Networking()
    private var observed: Set<String> = []
}
```

I have to manipulate `observed` and I need to create useful method to insert and remove member in `Set`.

```
mutating func addObserver(for member: String) {
    //other code
    observed.insert(member)
}

mutating func removeObserver(for member: String) {
    //other code
    observed.remove(member)
}
```

The problem is when I try to call this methods like this

```
Networking.shared.addObserver(for: "x")
```

because I'm getting this error

```
cannot use mutating on immutable value: “shared” is a “let” constant
```

This error is pretty clear. `shared` is `let` and obviously it cannot be modified. But to modify the `var` I need to declare method as mutating. It's a vicious circle.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you make Networking a class if you are using it as a Singleton?

Comment: A mutable value type cannot be a singleton – by definition, a singleton can only ever have one instance of itself. With a mutable value type, as soon as you mutate a copy of it, you've got different "instances".

Comment: Singletons by necessity are classes. If you want to use a struct for the preferences of the singleton that would work, but structs simply don't work with a singleton design.

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ You *could* have an immutable value type as a singleton – it would satisfy the semantics required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want your `Networking` object to act as a singleton, why not make it a class instead of a struct?

```
class Networking {

    static let shared = Networking()
    private var observed: Set<String> = []

    func addObserver(for member: String) {
        //other code
        observed.insert(member)
    }

    func removeObserver(for member: String) {
        //other code
        observed.remove(member)
    }
}

Networking.shared.addObserver(for: "x")
```

This simplifies the code and solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Basically your syntax is wrong, `Networking()` creates a new **instance** of the class.

To use the struct as singleton you have to write

```
Networking.shared.addObserver(for: "x")
```

Then declare `shared` as mutable

```
static var shared = Networking()
```

Comment: Sorry I've insert a typo. I've removed `Networking()`. But is correct declare shared as var? This violating the Singleton pattern

Comment: Actually the other solution using a `class` is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

There is also another way of doing it

```
class Networking {
    static let shared = Networking()
    var observed: Set<String> = [] {
        didSet {
            print("set has changed")
        }
    }
}
```

### Value Type

Since `Set` is a struct (a value type), the `didSet` block will be executed every time you add or remove and element to `Set`.

```
Networking.shared.observed.insert("a")
```

> set has changed

```
Networking.shared.observed.insert("b")
```

> set has changed

```
Networking.shared.observed.remove("a")
```

> set has changed